# Mongodb - aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, aggregation-framework

In my mongoDB payment collection I have documents structured as follow:

```
{
  "created_at": created_at,
  "amount": amount
  ...
}
```

I need to group records by month, sum amounts in every group and for every group find growth, something like that:

```
[{
  "created_at": "2014-11-13",
  "amount": 10    
},
{
  "created_at": "2014-11-3",
  "amount": 20    
},
{
  "created_at": "2014-12-13",
  "amount": 30    
},   
{
  "created_at": "2014-12-15",
  "amount": 15    
}]
```

And result:

```
[{
 "_id": {"month": 11},
 "amount": 30,
 "growth": null
},
{
 "_id": {"month": 12},
 "amount": 45,
 "growth": 1.5    
}]
```

Is it possible to do with aggregation pipeline or map reduce or any other technique?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Artyom, it works best if you do some research first and include what you've got so far in your question.  This reads more like a work order which is frowned upon.

Comment: Which criteria set for growth?

Comment: @yogesh growth[i] = amount[i] / amount[i-1]

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
    {
    '$group' : {
        '_id' : {
            'month' : { '$month' : '$created_at'}
        },
        'amount' : { '$sum' : '$amount'}
    }
}
```